# EXT JS 4 Adding Query String to Links

Tags: extjs, hyperlink, components, extjs4

Whenever I create a component with a url, Ext Js 4 is adding ?undefined to the link.  How can I get rid of that?

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
                Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {"items":[{"text":"Dashboard","xtype":"button","target":"_self","href":"https:\/\/domain.tld\/admin\/"},{"text":"Categories","xtype":"button","menu":{"items":[{"text":"New","xtype":"button","target":"_self","href":"https:\/\/domain.tld\/admin\/category\/create\/"}]}}],"renderTo":"admin_menu","width":"100%"});
            });
```

Clicking dashboard takes you to https://domain.tld/admin/dashboard?undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source to figure out how it was creating urls.  It takes the href config and appends the params config without checking to see if params is defined.  Then appends the baseParams config.  So if you want a link without the query string, create your button with an empty params config.

Ext.create("Ext.button.Button", {href: 'www.google.com', params:'',text:'Link',target:'_self'});

Answer (score 0):

[ExtJS documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html) doesn't mention `href` as a supported config option for Toolbar.

Instead of specifying `target` and `href`, I suggest specifying a handler function. Something to the effect of :

```
{
  text:'Dashboard',
  handler:function(){
    //window.open(...) or window.location.href=...
  }
//...
}
```

Comment: true the docs dont mention it but if you look at the config, its a supported config option